# How to have Windows Performance Monitor User Defined sets start at system startup

Tags: windows, performance-monitor

I know you can set a timing schedule; but I'd really prefer to have them start once the computer starts. How do I do this?

Comment: can you not start it at startup?

Comment: No you can only specify a time (schedule) to start it

Comment: The answer to this problem is to use logman start "custom policy" as a startup script for Scheduled Tasks/Task Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Add a shortcut to `perfmon.exe` in the StartUp menu. It has not the exact behaviour as clicking performance in `taskmgr.exe` but maybe you'll find it useful enough.